# Is it possible to get what package.json script has been called in NodeJS code?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Is it possible to get what package.json script has been called in NodeJS code?

My package.json file contains a script that builds the application:

```
{
    "name": "notes-app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build && node server.js"
    },
    etc, etc...
```

Can I then write in my server.js file an if statement like:

```
if (script === 'build') {
  // Do something
}
```

Is there a way of knowing what script was called when starting the app. I would start this using the command `npm run build`. Also I'm using **windows** if that would make any difference.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

I agree with yury, you must be detecting this for a reason, and maybe a more fit solution lies in that context.

However, when this is important (like for system administration) it is usually done by setting an environment variable in the scripts section and then testing process.env in the node js.